# How can I check the item size of a request in dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, throttling, ondemand

We are using a dynamodb with on-demand capacity mode. We are suddenly seeing few of our requests getting write throttled. During the same time frame there is sudden spike in Write Capacity Units (WCU).

I have checked the incoming traffic/ write request count and it is pretty much the same.

1. Does this mean the WCU increase is due to increase in item size?
2. How can I verify the size of my request?
3. Since our dynamodb is already provisioned in on-demand mode, why is it unable to auto scale and handle the requests given that traffic is pretty much the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It's possible
2. You can return the consumed capacity for each write operation which will allow you to understand which items are consuming more capacity. [ReturnConsumedCapacity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html#DDB-PutItem-request-ReturnConsumedCapacity)
3. On-demand mode tables can throttle for 3 reasons:

   - You exceed twice your previous peak in 30 mins
   - You exceed partition hard limit of 1000 WCU / 3000 RCU (hot partition)
   - You have GSI backoressure where you're GSI has a hot partition

You can enable [CloudWatch Contributor Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/contributorinsights_HowItWorks.html) to understand if you have a hot key(s).